# How to get multiple $http when Consume Restful APIs with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, rest

I try to get from JSONPlaceholder data to display, and I need more than one `$http.get` , this is my code. The problem is, that from the second call I don't get any data

```
  MyAlbum1.controller('albumList', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums').
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.albumDetails = response.data;
        });

    $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.albumUsers = response.data;
       });
});
```

If I try for example to display in the partial view `albumUsers.name` it will not display. Only if I put first the `$http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').` but then it will not display the `albumDetails.id`

So how do I get more than one `http.get`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could load 1 after another:

```
MyAlbum1.controller('albumList', function($scope, $http) {

     $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums').
     then(function(response) {
        $scope.albumDetails = response.data;


        $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').
        then(function(response) {
                $scope.albumUsers = response.data;
        });
    });
});
```

or

```
  MyAlbum1.controller('albumList', function($scope, $http, $q) {
       $q.all([$http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'), $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')]).then(function(response) { 
       });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$q` to send multiple requests at once.first inject the `$q` to controller.

```
MyAlbum1.controller('albumList', function($scope, $http,$q) {    

    $q.all(['http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums','http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',]).then(function(response){
         $scope.albumDetails = response[0].data;
         $scope.albumUsers= response[1].data;
    })    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Work now. Here's the code I'm using:

```
MyAlbum.controller('albumList', function($scope, $http, $q) {
$http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums').
    then(function(response) {
        $scope.albumDetails = response.data;
    });

$http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').
    then(function(response) {
        $scope.albumUsers = response.data;
   });

$q.all(['http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums','http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',]).
    then(function(response){
        $scope.albumDetails = response[0].data;
        $scope.albumUsers= response[1].data;
});
```

});

But, when call the data, I need to do as follow:

```
User: {{albumUsers[1].name}}
```

Like, I need the [1] in order that it will work. 
Thanks